# Replace all CRLF with \r\n using REXEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, newline, regexp-replace

I have a process that needs to strip all CRLF from SQL statements and store them with literal characters \r\n and stores this in a .json file. Later, this process is reversed when the .json file is inserted back into the database.

I am using ORACLE 19c.

The original (abbreviated) SQL might look like this:

```
SELECT SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME
FROM sztdhof
LEFT JOIN SPRIDEN
ON sztdhof.SZTDHOF_PIDM = spriden.SPRIDEN_PIDM
RIGHT JOIN SSBSECT
ON sztdhof_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN 
WHERE spriden_change_ind IS NULL
```

The resulting string should look like this:

```
SELECT SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME\r\nFROM sztdhof\r\nLEFT JOIN SPRIDEN\r\nON sztdhof.SZTDHOF_PIDM = spriden.SPRIDEN_PIDM\r\nRIGHT JOIN SSBSECT\r\nON sztdhof_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN \r\nWHERE spriden_change_ind IS NULL
```

I have tried numerous ways to get ORACLE REGEXP_REPLACE to recognize the carriage return and line feed together. None seem to work.

To start, I read the value from the db into a variable v_text. Then I attempt the conversion and placing the result into a second variable v_outtext. If I use two separate statements, each works separately. And I can live with that method, but I would like this to work as a single statement. (Note. I have also tried the REPLACE function with similar results.)

This code...

```
SELECT REPLACE (v_text, chr(13) , '\r\n')
    INTO v_outtext
    FROM dual;
```

produces...

```
SELECT SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME\r\n
FROM sztdhof\r\n
LEFT JOIN SPRIDEN\r\n
ON sztdhof.SZTDHOF_PIDM = spriden.SPRIDEN_PIDM\r\n
RIGHT JOIN SSBSECT\r\n
ON sztdhof_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN \r\n
WHERE spriden_change_ind IS NULL\r\n
```

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(v_text, chr(10) , '\r\n')` --is  similar to above, except the \r\n are at the front of each line.

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(v_text, (chr(13)chr(10) , '\r\n')` gives me an error, missing right parenthesis.

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (v_text, '(\r\n)', '\r\n')` replaces r with \r and n with \n, but only the first instance.

I have tried numerous iterations. None solve the problem. Any thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the two characters you want to replace, not just put them in parentheses (even if you supplied both):

```
SELECT REPLACE(v_text, chr(13) || chr(10) , '\r\n')
INTO v_outtext
FROM dual;
```

If if it's already in a PL/SQL variable you don't need to to the context switch to select from dual; you can simplify to:

```
v_outtext := REPLACE(v_text, chr(13) || chr(10) , '\r\n');
```

but it sounds like you can use the first method to read the value from the database into `v_outtext` in one go, without the intermediate `v_text`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=04dfad2f0a763b2064b210ee2a83f47d)

Comment: Thank you Alex, I had tried that solution 10 times, with a slight change....  I had left the quotation marks around the front of chr(13) || chr(10) like this,  'chr(13) || chr(10)'. Of course that made it search for the string, not the separate characters.   I knew there had to be something simple I was overlooking. 

Also, thanks for the link to db<>fiddle. I had never used that before...a great resource.